# Is the set $\{ (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n} ~ : ~ \frac{u}{\|u\|} = \frac{v}{\|v\|} \}$ a submanifold?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^d_0 := \mathbb{R}^d \backslash \{0\}$. For $n \geq 2$, consider the set
\begin{align}
M = \{ (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^n_0 \times \mathbb{R}^n_0 ~ : ~ \| v \| u = \| u \| v \} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n} .
\end{align}
I would like to know if $M$ is a submanifold and, if so, whether it is diffeomorphic to a well-studied space. I am especially interested in visualizing the low dimensional $n=2,3$ cases. My differential topology is very rusty, so I could use some guidance.

**Simple Observations:**

My naive idea was to use the [preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem). Note that $M = f^{-1} (0)$ where $f : \mathbb{R}^n_0 \times \mathbb{R}^n_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by
\begin{align}
f(u,v) = \| v \| u - \| u \| v . 
\end{align}
Clearly $f$ is smooth. If $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a regular point of $f$, then $M$ would be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n_0 \times \mathbb{R}^n_0$ of (co)dimension $n$. By definition, $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a regular point of $f$ if, for all $(u,v) \in M$, then $Df (u,v) : \mathbb{R}^n_0 \times \mathbb{R}^n_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is surjective. However, my computations show that $Df (u,v)$ for $(u,v) \in M$ is *not* surjective. So the preimage theorem doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb R_0^n \cong \Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1}$, so that $M$ can be considered a subset of $(\Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1}) \times (\Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1})$. In this formulation, isn't $M$ exactly $\{ ((\alpha,s),(\beta,s))\colon \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R_{>0},\, s\in S^{n-1} \}$? And if that's the case, isn't $M$ naturally diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R_{>0} \times \Bbb R_{>0}\times S^{n-1}$?

Comment: @GregMartin This seems to be correct. Thank you. You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f\colon \Bbb R_{>0} \times \Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1} \to \Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1} \times \Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1}$ given by $f(\alpha,\beta,s)=(\alpha,s,\beta,s)$, and the map $g\colon \Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1} \times \Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1} \to \Bbb R^n_0 \times \Bbb R^n_0$ given by $g(\alpha,s,\beta,t) = (\alpha s,\beta t)$. Then the image of the differential manifold $\Bbb R_{>0} \times \Bbb R_{>0} \times S^{n-1}$ under $g\circ f$ is exactly $M$, and one can check that $g\circ f$ is in fact a diffeormorphism onto its image.